using ec2-instance-connect with --local-forwarding for sublime ssh tunnel
I use sublime to edit files on remote AWS EC2 instances with remote port forwarding, by installing rmate on the remote machine, as described here:
https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl
Then, if I connect with standard ssh methods using an identify file, I include the following in my .ssh/config for the connection:
RemoteForward 52698 localhost:52698

This has worked well for me for years.
However, when I try to use ec2-instance-connect I run the following (note the --local-forwarding 52698:localhost:52698):
aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id i-xxxxxxx --os-user foo --profile dev --local-forwarding 52698:localhost:52698

This connects fine (using a profile I setup with aws sso), but when I try to open a file on the remote instance, I get:
$ rsubl foo.py 
/usr/local/bin/rsubl: connect: Connection refused
/usr/local/bin/rsubl: line 412: /dev/tcp/localhost/52698: Connection refused
Unable to connect to TextMate on localhost:52698

Any ideas on how I can get ec2-instance-connect and port forwarding to work for my use case?

You don't need a tunnel here.  You should be able to configure ssh to use ssm behind the scenes:   https://felixhammerl.com/2024/03/12/no-more-bastion-hosts.html.  Assuming sublime would pick up that ssh config, which it ought to, you should just be able to enter your instance ID into the config and ssh i-exampleblah

@erik258 following the example in that link, I tried setting up my ssh config using the instance ID as the hostname, and if I have a .pem key, then yes this works. I did not know about ProxyCommand! However, I would like to connect without requiring a .pem key, and this is why I have been trying aws sso to get an SSO authorized session, and then the ec2-instance-connect ssh to make the ssh connection. Is there a way to use the config as you suggest, but without needing a .pem key?
